# Why does bash script print output

Tags: bash

Bash newcomer here. I'm trying to write a script that loops over some terminal output, formats each line, then stores the result in a file.

```
gopass environment-variables | while read line; do

   if [ "$line" != "environment-variables" ]; then

       echo ${line:4} >> variables.txt

   fi

done
```

When I run this in my terminal (GNU Bash 3.2.57, macOS High Sierra) it works just fine, but when I run it as a shell script the expected output is followed by the original terminal output! Help! Please?

FYI:

```
gopass environment-variables
```

outputs

```
environment-variables/
|---- C_MONSTER
|---- D_MONSTER
|---- E_MONSTER
```

I want to see

```
C_MONSTER
E_MONSTER
D_MONSTER
```

In the file.

Comment: `while read` will consume everything written to stdout. It doesn't see anything written to stderr, or to the TTY. Thus, it's important to know (and describe in the question) what `gopass` writes to which specific file descriptor.

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly suggest logging your script's operation -- `PS4=':${BASH_LINENO##*/}:$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` will run `yourscript` with each line logged so you can see exactly what the shell is up to. Won't help with content written by `gopass` to a file descriptor that bypasses the shell, of course.

Comment: That said, what I'd suggest you try to do at this point is build a [mcve] that people who don't have a copy of `gopass` can run. For instance, do you get the same behavior with `gopass() { printf '%s\n' 'environment-variables/' '|---- C_MONSTER' '|---- D_MONSTER' '|---- E_MONSTER'; }`? If not, that strongly implies that something `gopass` is doing is an essential element of the problem (and that we won't be able to help you find a solution without it).

Comment: (Also, for a password manager, it would be *very very typical* for it to intentionally write straight to the TTY to bypass attempts at capture/logging -- what you're running into is liable to be a feature, not a bug).

Comment: You're right. Defining a my own `gopass` did not behave the same as the real thing. BUT I solved the issue using `head` to grab the lines I needed from the file. Thanks!